# android gradle hang by creating new cache

Tags: android, linux, gradle

I need to create a gradle build server to auto build our android project. after I set java,android sdk,gradle all done .

then I copied my macbook's folder ".gradle" on this server(*Just for avoid re-downloading*),

now I got hangged everytime after execute "./gradlew assemble --info". 
the log is hang message are following:

```
    Creating new cache for metadata-2.23/module-metadata, path /root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.23/module-metadata.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@4ed31790

    Creating new cache for metadata-2.23/artifact-at-repository, path /root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.23/artifact-at-repository.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@4ed31790

    Creating new cache for metadata-2.23/artifact-at-url, path /root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.23/artifact-at-url.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@4ed31790

    > Configuring > 0/4 projects > root project
```

someone can help me ? appreciate any help :)